# What is the Effective Resolution of 7135 ADC

Tags: adc

What is the effective resolution of Intersil 7135 based 4.5Digit ADC

when we use a Microcontroller based measurement using the BUSY and STROBE Signals?

[datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/icl7135.pdf)

[Data Sheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7135.pdf)

Comment: The data sheet or a link to it would be nice.

Comment: www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7135.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution if you 'and' with the externally supplied ADC clock is 1 count or 1 in 20,000. If the external clock was synchronized with a microcontroller timing peripheral you could conceivably do better, but it will be limited by the noise floor, which is **typically** 15uV-30uV to two sigmas, so it's conceivable to get to a typical resolution of 1 part in 50,000 (about 15-16bits).

Comment: Can you be a little bit more forthcoming about 'and'ing with externally supplied clock and synchronizing external clock with a micro controller timing peripheral.

Comment: See the relevant paragraph in the [datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7135.pdf). Synchronized just means that you'd use a higher frequency clock for the micro peripheral (usually that means using it for the main clock too) and divide it down to get the low frequency clock the ADC uses to time the integration cycle.